# jQuery focusin event bound to body cant workout links parents correctly?

Tags: jquery

I need to have events for when anything is focused on. I need different events depending if the element is within a div with a certain class or not.

For performance reasons I want to call the function on the body rather than every link on the page. This is also so I can easily unbind it later.

Why is this not working? If it just a syntax issue?

If possible id like a solution as close to my approach as possible, party for consistency in my code and also so I understand where ive gone wrong.

```
  function something() {
    if ($(':focus').parents('.myclass').length) {
      console.log('yes');
    } else {
      console.log('no');
    }
  }

  $('body').bind('focusin', something);
```

This is a simplified version of my HTML. I need an event for when you focus on Link1 and Link2, and a different event for when you focus on Link3 or Link4.

```
<a href="#">Link1</a>
<a href="#">Link2</a>
<div class="myclass">
  <a href="#">Link3</a>
  <a href="#">Link4</a>
</div>
```

If I try the following all that is logged is "undefined" so could the issue be with the :focus selector?

```
  function something() {
    if ($(':focus').parents('.myclass').length) {
      var test = $(':focus').attr('class');
      console.log(test);
    } else {
      var test = $(':focus').attr('class');
      console.log(test);        
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can include `html` at Question ?, create stacksnippets , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `event.target` instead of `:focus` and everything should work fine:

```
function something(e) {
    if ($(e.target).parents('.myclass').length) {
        console.log('yes');
    } else {
        console.log('no');
    }
}
$(function() {
    $('body').bind('focusin', something);
});
```

```js
function something(e) {
    if ($(e.target).parents('.myclass').length) {
      console.log('yes');
    } else {
      console.log('no');
    }
}

$(function() {
    $('body').bind('focusin', something);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myclass">
  <input type="text" name="test"/>
</div>
<div class="not-myclass">
  <input type="text" name="test1"/>
</div>
<a href="#">Link1</a>
<a href="#">Link2</a>
<div class="myclass">
  <a href="#">Link3</a>
  <a href="#">Link4</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `this` instead of `:focus` to target the specific element that triggered `focusin`

```
 $('body').bind('focusin', function() {
     if ($(this).parents('.myclass').length) {
         console.log('yes');
     } else {
         console.log('no');
     }
});
```

OR

```
function something(elem) {
    if (elem.parents('.myclass').length) {
      console.log('yes');
    } else {
      console.log('no');
    }
  }

$('body').bind('focusin', something($(this));
```